# Sum Of All Rows into One Row at first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need some help with sum future . I am trying the sum of marks and sum of expected marks in 
last row.

Here is what I want.
I am inserting standard , marks, expected marks and  deviation into temp table.
here temp table has an identity column.

```
Create table #temp( id int identity(1,1),
standard varchar(20), marks int, [expected marks] int,
deviation float
) 
Insert into #temp 
select * from mytable


id  standard    marks   expectedmarks   Deviation in %
0   Total       205       299           31.43812709
1   1st          50        60           16.66666667
2   2nd          60        80           25
3   3rd          45        70           35.71428571
4   5th          50        89           43.82022472
```

Here I want to insert total of  marks , expected marks and deviation at last
and would be display at as first row

```
select * from temp 
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` to include the `SUM` in the result and `ORDER BY id`:

```
select
    id, standard, marks, expectedmarks, deviation 
from temp 
union all
select 
    0, 'Total', sum(marks), sum(expectedmarks), sum(deviation)
from temp
order by id asc
```

Comment: Sorry, completely missed that. Replace it with `'Total'` instead.